# Normally distributed vector given mean, stddev|variance

Tags: python, random, pytorch, normal-distribution

how to do this in torch

```
 np.random.normal(loc=mean,scale=stdev,size=vsize)
```

i.e. by providing mean, stddev or variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar torch function [torch.normal](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.normal.html):

```
torch.normal(mean=mean, std=std)
```

If mean and std are scalars, this will produce a scalar value. You can simply repeat them for the target you want it to be, eg:

```
mean = 2
std = 10
size = (3,3)
r = torch.normal(mean=torch.full(size,mean).float(),std=torch.full(size,mean).float())
print(r)

> tensor([[ 2.2263,  1.1374,  4.5766],
    [ 3.4727,  2.6712,  2.4878],
    [-0.1787,  2.9600,  2.7598]])
```

Comment: thanks, this did it torch.normal(0.0,1/10,size=(10,))